Longest Repeating Subsequence: Edge Cases
Problem
While solving the Longest Repeating Subsequence problem using bottom-up dynamic programming, I started running into an edge case whenever a letter was repeated an odd number of times.
The goal is to find the longest subsequence that occurs twice in the string using elements at different indices. The ranges can overlap, but the indices should be disjoint (i.e., str[1], str[4] and str[2], str[6] can be a solution, but not str[1], str[2] and str[2], str[3]).
EDIT: Misunderstood example. (See the comment)
Minimum Reproducible Example
s = 'AXXXA'

n = len(s)

dp = [['' for i in range(n + 1)] for j in range(n + 1)]

for i in range(1, n + 1):
  for j in range(1, n + 1):
    if (i != j and s[i - 1] == s[j - 1]):
      dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1] + s[i - 1]
    else:
      dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])

print(dp[n][n])

Question
Any pointers on how to avoid this?
With input s = 'AXXXA', the answer should be either A or X, but the final result returns XX, apparently pairing up the third X with both the first X and the second X.
False Start
I don't want to add a check on a match (s[i - 1] == s[j - 1]) to see if s[i - 1] in dp[i - 1][j - 1] because another input might be something like AAJDDAJJTATA, which must add the A twice.

Why did you accept an answer that directly contradicts your "indices should be disjoint" requirement?

I was attempting a problem from a book, and the example was my own, based on what I understood from disjoint. As the accepted answer points out, that is not the understanding of disjointness in LRS. (I didn't realise I should've made an edit here. Sorry if I've caused some confusion.)

Thanks for responding. I still strongly suspect that, by even mentioning the word "disjoint", the book problem did indeed intend the problem to be as you interpreted it. Does the book itself clarify? Because, interestingly, it turns out that the problem as you interpreted is actually NP-complete, even if we restrict it by requiring every character to belong to one of the 2 "halves", so it is almost certainly not solvable in O(n^2) time: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/130796/1984

Actually, your initial algorithm and its answer are correct (... but this is a good question because others might confuse what an LRS means).
Given your input (in), the subsequences (s1, s2) are:
in: AXXXA
s1:  XX
s2:   XX

So XX (length 2) is indeed the correct answer here.
X would be the correct answer for the problem's non-overlapping version, where the ranges - not just individual indices - must be disjoint.

Not sure why the author accepted this... their own "indices should be disjoint" criteria ("but not str[1], str[2] and str[2], str[3]") specifically disallows exactly this scenario. Although "disjoint" with no further qualifications could indeed mean several things, the fact that they gave that example of an invalid solution means that they intend for all used indices to be disjoint.

Thanks for pointing this out. The description as an LRS problem threw me off and I reasoned about the incorrectness of the expected return.

You can keep track of the indices of the last added characters, and make sure that when two characters are the same, their indices have to be not only different to each other but also to that of the last added character:
s = 'AXXXA'
n = len(s)
dp = [[('', 0, 0) for i in range(n + 1)] for j in range(n + 1)]

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        last = dp[i - 1][j - 1]
        if last[2] != i != j != last[1] and s[i - 1] == s[j - 1]:
            dp[i][j] = last[0] + s[i - 1], i, j
        else:
            dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1], key=lambda t: t[0])

print(dp[n][n][0]) # outputs X

Demo: https://ideone.com/mSKgKy

I think you meant key=lambda t: len(t[0]), since, e.g., max('abc', 'de') == 'de'. But that's not the most serious issue here: Even after fixing this, input AAAAA incorrectly gives AAA instead of AA: https://ideone.com/iMvV0F.

The problem is that, since you only track the two endpoints (and not all other used indices), you can incorrectly allow indices to be reused by the second string if they are "well back from the tip" of the first.

Separately, I think this algorithm is also broken in the other direction (being too pessimistic on some inputs), though I haven't yet found an example for that: Since for each (i, j) there could be multiple equally good end position pairs, but you only track one such pair, if the tracked pair hits a conflict, you will pessimistically assume no subsequence pair can be extended (when some other equally good subsequence pair ending at different positions possibly could be).


For retrieving the longest, it's best to implement a new function, with the result of dp grid.

Your algorithm is fine, you only need to increment your new dp by 1, when s[i - 1] == s[j - 1]:


    n = len(s)
    dp = [[0 for _ in range(n + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            if s[i - 1] == s[j - 1] and i != j:
                dp[i][j] = 1 + dp[i - 1][j - 1]
            else:
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])

    return dp[-1][-1]


If you want to build the longest, you can use the dp grid and whenever the if s[i - 1] == s[j - 1] and i != j satisfies, append the char to the longest:
    def get_longest():
        i, j = n, n
        lrs = []
        while i > 0 and j > 0:
            if s[i - 1] == s[j - 1] and i != j:
                lrs.append(s[i - 1])
                i -= 1
                j -= 1
            elif dp[i - 1][j] > dp[i][j - 1]:
                i -= 1
            else:
                j -= 1

        return ''.join(lrs[::-1])

Code
def LRS(s):
    def get_longest():
        i, j = n, n
        lrs = []
        while i > 0 and j > 0:
            if s[i - 1] == s[j - 1] and i != j:
                lrs.append(s[i - 1])
                i -= 1
                j -= 1
            elif dp[i - 1][j] > dp[i][j - 1]:
                i -= 1
            else:
                j -= 1

        return ''.join(lrs[::-1])
    n = len(s)
    dp = [[0 for _ in range(n + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            if s[i - 1] == s[j - 1] and i != j:
                dp[i][j] = 1 + dp[i - 1][j - 1]
            else:
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1])
    print(get_longest())
    return dp[-1][-1]


s = 'AXXXA'
print(LRS(s))


Prints
XX
2

This answer is actually correct. See my explanation below (or above, as the votes go).
